# jQuery mobile - scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Hello all and thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I really appreciate it.

I'm using jqm 1.0 (stable) to build a mobile version of web app. I have two sets of `<ul>`s on the page and I have the following problem:

the second i touch the screen to swipe up or down it changes the style of the `<li>` (which has a nested `<a>` tag) as if it were clicked. It does not fire the click event, it just changes its style and for a second or two it stays like that, as if it were clicked. Do you know how I can change this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. To avoid this simply remove the a tag you have in your list item.